# Local instance of the MultipartUtility class is thread safe in java?

Tags: java, thread-safety

Is [MultipartUtility](https://mail.codejava.net/java-se/networking/upload-files-by-sending-multipart-request-programmatically) object instance "multipartUtil" in "uploadFile" method is thread safe? I believe instance address will be stored in stack and object will be stored in heap. This MultipartUtility class is having class level variables. If the object instance can only be accessed by that particular thread, then all variables expected static variables on the class considered thread safe?

```
public class MyController {
    public ResponseEntity<String> uploadFile(String stringUrl, MultipartFile multiPartFile) {       
        String charset = "UTF-8";
        String contentType = "multipart/form-data";
        String agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10.4; en-US; rv:1.9.2.2) Gecko/20100316 Firefox/3.6.2";
        
            MultipartUtility multipartUtil = new MultipartUtility(stringUrl, charset); 
            multipartUtil.addHeaderField("User-Agent", agent);
            multipartUtil.addHeaderField("Content-Type", contentType);
            File fileObj = new File(multiPartFile.getOriginalFilename()); 
            multipartUtil.addFilePart("fileUpload", fileObj);
            List<String> response = multipartUtil.finish(); 
            StringBuilder responseStr = new StringBuilder();
            for (String line : response) {
                responseStr.append(line);
            }           
            return new ResponseEntity<String>(responseStr.toString(), HttpStatus.OK);       
    }
}
```

Comment: It's fine since you're creating a new instance each time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The object itself seems to be threadsafe since the fields are all immutable.

However the objects like the writer and connection should not be used concurrently:

```
 public void addFormField(String name, String value) {
        writer.append("--" + boundary).append(LINE_FEED);
        writer.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"" + name + "\"")
                .append(LINE_FEED);
        writer.append("Content-Type: text/plain; charset=" + charset).append(
                LINE_FEED);
        writer.append(LINE_FEED);
        writer.append(value).append(LINE_FEED);
        writer.flush();
    }
```

If this would be called concurrently, then the writer could end up an interleaving of 2 requests.

Based on the example code above, it seems there is no concurrency problem (as Unmitigated already pointed out) since the instance isn't shared between threads.